# foreignObject rendering issue in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg

I have created one drawing tool which is based on svg, in which we can create different kinds of objects and also drag and resize them. For some of the objects I am using foreignObject to display html elements inside svg.

For e.g. I am using contentEditable div as sticky note in svg. But when I apply dragging to this sticky note it is behaving weirdly and rendering is strange in teh Chrome browser (Version 52.0.2743.82 m). What might be the issue?

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/qwg3r/913/
(Pick yellow sticky note and try to drag it)

[image]

```
<svg width="100%" height="500">
  <foreignObject id="1" x="10" y="10" width="100" height="150">
    <div autofocus="" style="position: relative;padding: 10px; width: 100%; height: auto; border-bottom-left-radius: 60px 8px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 2px 6px; display: inline-block; word-wrap: break-word; font-size: 13px; text-align: center; min-height: 156.499px; background: rgb(251, 234, 149);z-index:12;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" focus-preventer="" contenteditable="true"></div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

**P.S.** I am using some sort of settings icon in the top left corner of the sticky note to customize its color and other things, so I have used z-index in its div style so that settings icon will always be visible even if it is outside of drawing panel.

Comment: What's the issue? A bug presumably, report it to the Chrome bugtracker.

Comment: Works fine with same Chrome version (64bit) on Linux.